# How to fix AccessDeniedException at aws root account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

When I trying to deploy some code to aws lamda using serverless framework, i got this exception in cloudformation logs

```
Resource handler returned message: "null (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 6d65524e..., Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: 0e02ad46-c93c-2935...., HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
```

How I can deal with it? I using root account to deploy. (I know that is bad :) )

Comment: Also when I use aws-cli i got `An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListFunctions operation: None`

Comment: Is your account part of an organization? That API-call may be denied by a Service Control Policy, which also apply to root account users. You already know it, but **deploying with the Root Account User is a terrible idea**.

Comment: Absolutely) But it also reproducing with IAM credentials. Thanks, but it doesn't part of organization

Comment: Can you create a Lambda via the Console? It doesn't need to be the one that you're trying to deploy; just create and run the default "Hello World" Lambda.

Comment: Similar issue. `An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try send email to Amazon tech support. Your account may be suspected,  (you need approve billing info for example ). This was helpful in my case

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).